# Objects are automatically attaching themselves to rigify rig

Tags: constraints

My rigify rig has dotted lines to the world origin as if there are object constraints, however I haven't added any contraints. I am unable to add new objects in to my scene without them automatically attaching to my rig - if I add a cube and try to move it, the rig moves with it too. Does anyone have a clue as to why this is happening?

[image]

Comment: If it's a rigify rig, those are to the rig's _root_ bone.  Select the rig, go to pose mode, open the sidepanel (shortcut 'N') and see if "Root" is selected.  It's probably not, so the boen doesn't show up.

Comment: @MartyFouts Thanks for commenting. I couldn't find an option anywhere for 'root'. I ended up deleting the rigify and using the armature to pose instead.